# Is it worth investing in 401(k) if a company doesn't do matching?

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement, ira

The company offers 401(k) but doesn't match your contribution at all. In this case, it worth investing in 401(k)? For what reasons might a 401(k) be preferred over an IRA if there is no match?

Comment: As stated, this comment is too broad for a reasonable answer.  This must necessarily depend on a lot of other factors like your age, overall wealth, goals for retirement, etc.

Comment: If there's no employer match, I think a Roth IRA is the best option, unless you really need the tax deferral or have already made your maximum contribution for the year.

Comment: I've narrowed the question in an attempt to keep it open. If you have a more specific question about what types of accounts might be best for you personally, ask a new question and include more details about your situation.

Comment: @BenMiller [Should I contribute to my 401k with a high expense ratio and no matching?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/46370/should-i-contribute-to-my-401k-with-a-high-expense-ratio-and-no-matching) is quite similar in my opinion.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer It's very similar, although that question focuses on the fact that the OP's 401(k) has bad investments, so the answers deal with that.  Another similar question is [this one](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/38827/10997), but in it the OP is comparing investing in the 401(k) vs. not investing at all, and the answers deal with that.  Our question here is the only one really comparing 401(k) with no match vs. IRA.  I'd leave all three of them open.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, they will all stay. It's at times like this that a wiki-style curated index seems appealing to me. Retirement/401(k)/ marching, fees etc

Answer (score 26):

Besides the employer match, a 401(k) plan has other benefits that IRAs do not have:

- A 401(k) is convenient.  The investment is automatically taken out of every paycheck.  This encourages setting an investment plan and sticking to it.  For some people, it can be tempting to skip planned investments into an IRA.
- 401(k) plans can have higher annual investment limits.  If you would like to invest more than you are allowed in an IRA, your company's 401(k) might allow you to do this.
- 401(k) plans have no upper income limit to be eligible to contribute.  If you make too much money to contribute pre-tax to an IRA, you might still be able to invest in a 401(k).
- 401(k) plans sometimes allow you to borrow your own money from your 401(k) and pay yourself interest.  I don't recommend this practice for a few reasons, but this is an option that you don't get with an IRA.
- Under certain circumstances, a 401(k) can allow you to retire early and withdraw at age 55 vs. 59-1/2 with an IRA. (Thanks @JoeTaxpayer)

However, 401(k) plans also have downsides.  Inside a 401(k), you are generally limited to a handful of investment fund options selected by your employer.  With some plans, you might find that your only investment options come with high expenses.  With an IRA, you can invest in almost anything you want.

The [employer match](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/56536/10997) is the biggest benefit to the 401(k).  But even without it, the 401(k) could still be the best option for you.

For a very broad overview of different retirement accounts in the U.S., see [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/50149/10997).  If you have a more specific question, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Also a 401k still gives tax-advantages (details depend on the type of 401k), but that is basically free money in and of itself

Comment: Well, you pay tax on all money you take out later in a traditional 401K.  If you believe the US is headed towards higher tax rates in the future or you believe you will be paying higher taxes when you retire, max out a ROTH IRA (or ROTH 401K) first.

Comment: @TomCabanski `If you believe the US is head towards higher tax rates.` You mean when ;)

Comment: Even if rates overall are higher, you may be withdrawing at a rate that results in a lower tax bracket.  The taxes you defer when contributing to a 401K are at your marginal rate.

Comment: Great answer.  I'd just add that doing both a 401(k) and an IRA is quite possible.  For many people, the right way to go is with a maxed our IRA and then as much 401(k) as possible.  With a bit more work you can find what is right for you.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: IRA contributions are only deductible for folks with medium and low incomes.  As your income rises, eventually you can't deduct IRA contributes for tax purposes, but you can always deduct 401(k) contributions.

Comment: For those who are let go or retire early, the 401(k) age 55 rule allows penalty free withdrawals, vs IRA 59-1/2.

Comment: I would emphasize in the downsides the fact that in a 401(k) you are limited to what your employer chooses as investment options.  You sort of mention it in passing but it's a significant downside - not necessarily enough to counter the rest, but still.

Comment: I would also add that while investment choices are limited, you sometimes get access to institutional shares with lower expense ratios than you might be able to get in your own IRA.

Comment: “If you make too much money to contribute to an IRA” You can't "make too much to contribute to an IRA". No matter how high your income is, you can *contribute* to a Traditional IRA. There may be income limits for *deducting* a Traditional IRA contribution, but in the case where neither you nor your employer contributes to the 401(k) plan that year, there is no income limit.

Answer (score -2):

There is a possible case where a person might opt to not use the 401k at all.

If your income for the year is higher than the tIRA deduction limit, which probably means your tax bracket is in the +25% range, and you want to lower your tax on income this year, you might opt to contribute $0 to the 401k plan, and contribute to the tIRA the full amount ($5500 in 2018).

If no contributions have been made to any 401k plan through any employer for the year (Box 13 on your W2), then you are able to deduct the tIRA contribution for its full amount in your tax filing. Be aware, this includes Employer and Employee contributions total for the year.